# Angular 8 to 9 upgrade material index do not work as expected

Tags: angular8, angular9

having issues with <div *ngFor="let A of ANY; let t = index">
then using the t index <div *ngIf="prodT[t]"> generate error in angular 9 works in angular 8.

Comment: src/app/dialog-pop-offers/dialog-pop-offers.component.ts:18:16
    18   templateUrl: './dialog-pop-offers.component.html',
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component DialogPOPOffersComponent.
src/app/dialog-pop-offers/dialog-pop-offers.component.html:143:60 - error TS2339: Property 't' does not exist on type 'DialogPOPOffersComponent'.

Answer (score 0):

```
 @angular\cdk\__ivy_ngcc__\fesm2015

 add a try()catch() on material table.ts 

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this._rowOutlet.viewContainer.clear();
    try{
        this._noDataRowOutlet.viewContainer.clear();
    }catch{}
    this._headerRowOutlet.viewContainer.clear();
    this._footerRowOutlet.viewContainer.clear();
    this._cachedRenderRowsMap.clear();
    this._onDestroy.next();
    this._onDestroy.complete();
    if (isDataSource(this.dataSource)) {
        this.dataSource.disconnect(this);
    }
   }
```